# What's the minimum subfloor thickness required for hardwood flooring?

Tags: wood, flooring

I have a concrete slab and want to put 3/4 wood flooring on top.  I'm going to lay a plywood subfloor and want to know if 1/2 inch plywood is good enough. I plan on nailing down the wooden floor.

Comment: half an inch isn't a lot for a nail to grab into and not go through.  A one and half inch cleat will go completely through the half inch plywood and stick out about a 10th of a inch.  Typically when installing over concrete slab, you float an engineered floor.  A high quality engineered floor will look/last the same as a solid wood.

Comment: What is your current ceiling height?  What is the minimum ceiling height you are willing to accept?

Comment: What about glueing it down?

Answer (score 2):

Agree with diceless that a floating engineered wooden floor is more normal over a concrete slab. Thermal movement in fully fixed wooden floors causes problematical expansion/contraction more often than not.

Even using stable wood, the humidity in the room will change season to season, as will the temperature of the underlying/surrounding structure, all can affect the appearance of the wooden floor.

Was there a specific design/idea you had in specifying the ply subfloor?

Comment: Wet plywood sandwich, my favorite.